# How do you prevent a jquery.qtip2 tooltip from hiding when the mouse is over the tip?

Tags: qtip2

Using [jquery qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) for tooltips.

I have a tooltip with a link in it. I want the tip to stay open if the user's mouse enters the tip (not the trigger). Can't seem to figure out how to do that in the [documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/)....

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want it to remain visible when you mouse over and into the tip, but still want it to dismiss on mouseout, use the fixed and delay options as [described in the documentation here](http://qtip2.com/options#hide.fixed):

```
$('.selector').qtip({
     content: {
          text: 'I hide on mouseout, but you can mouse into me within 500ms',
     },
     hide: {
          fixed: true,
          delay: 500
     }
});
```

The hide parameter has many options.  For example, if you just want to not hide it indefinitely, simply set hide to false:

```
$('.selector').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'I never hide',
    },
    hide: false
});
```

If you want it to hide on a different event, such as clicking anywhere outside the tip, set the event explicitly:

```
$('.selector').qtip({
     content: {
          text: 'I hide when you click anywhere else on the document',
     },
     hide: {
          event: 'unfocus'
     }
});
```

If you want it to hide when the trigger is clicked, specify the click event:

```
$('.selector').qtip({
     content: {
          text: 'I hide when you click the tooltip trigger',
     },
     hide: {
          event: 'click'
     }
});
```

See specifically [the "hide" options documentation](http://qtip2.com/options#hide) for more info.

Comment: thank you so much.. it helped me a lot.. i was just finding this only.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the tip to stay open and then hide it when the user clicks outside the target or leaves the target:

```
show: {
    event: 'mouseover'
},

hide: {
     event: 'click mouseleave'
}
```